# How to reproduce EXC_BAD_ACCESS in generic case

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I've been playing around in Objective-C and was trying to purposefully get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash. What are some sure ways to achieve this?

I read that `Whenever you encounter EXC_BAD_ACCESS, it means that you are sending a message to an object that has already been released`. What is meant by the phrase "sending a message to an object"?

Something that  I tried to achieve the crash but did not succeed:

```
 __weak NSMutableArray *array;
    NSLog(@"%@", array)
    [array insertObject:@2 atIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", array.firstObject)
```

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` *does not always mean that you are messaging an already released object*.  It simply means you are de-referencing an invalid address.

Comment: Hi @bbum. Can you elaborate?

Comment: This provides a pretty decent explanation. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-exc_bad_access-and-how-to-debug-it--cms-24544

Comment: @bbum this is great, thank you

Comment: you can use __unsafe_unretained instead of __weak to produce an EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending `insert:atIndex:` to `array`.

The code does not crash because in Objective-C it's allowed to send a message to `nil`.

`array` is `nil` because it's declared but not initialized (yet).

---

You can reproduce a crash by declaring an object property with `assign` attibute

```
@property (assign) NSMutableArray *array;
```

Then create a method

```
- (void)insertSomething {
    self.array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self.array insertObject:@2 atIndex:0];
}
```

and call it

```
[self insertSomething];
NSLog(@"%@", self.array.firstObject);
```

Due to the `assign` attribute `array` is a weak reference and gets released right after leaving the `insertSomething` method.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a scenario where a weak property would cause a EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: No, as far as I know. A weak property is certainly set to `nil` when being released.